# Underline text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to make it so that when a div with the class "dropdown" is hovered over, a certain piece of text with the id "workButton" would underline. I would like to do this using jQuery, unless it is possible to make it happen in CSS. I currently have it so that when the text is hovered over it underlines and turns white, but I would like the same to happen when "dropdown" is hovered over. (the text with the id "workbutton" also has the class "menuContent")

CSS:

```
.menuContent:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.menuContent {
    font-family: "cicle-gordita";
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #b4b0b0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.dropdown {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-menuBit {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.dropdown-menuContent {
    font-family: "cicle-gordita";
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #b4b0b0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menuContent:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var main = function() {
  $('.dropdown').hide(function() {
    $('.main').animate({
      top: "-50px"
    }, 0);
  });

  $('#workButton').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown').fadeIn(1)

    $('.main').animate({
      top: "0px"
    }, 100)
  });

  $('.main, #blogButton, #homeButton, .logo').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown').fadeOut(200)

    $('.main').animate({
      top: "-50px"
    }, 200)
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the `:hover` on the parent and it should work just fine:

```
.dropdown:hover #workButton
```

Comment: Hi @TobyKing if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Okay have done that although I have now encountered a problem where the sub menu seems to have formatted weirdly, as if the '.dropdown-menuContent' sizes have been adjusted when putting in '.dropdown:hover #workButton' but I cannot find any reason as to why this may be happening

Comment: @TobyKing That is not possible, unless the `.dropdown:hover #workButton` is having the CSS which makes it look weird, though a `text-decoration: underline` should not be displaying badly. Try removing that part, make your other CSS look well, then add this part again.

Comment: Hmm alright I'll have a little play around and see what I can do. Thanks a lot for the help though